# How to add dynamic Bootstrap date picker field?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I want to add bootstrap date picker like the below link. I have tried but same class making problem.
How can i do this??

http://jsfiddle.net/SJ7bJ/98/

```
    <div id="content">
    a datepicker <input class="datepicker_recurring_start"/>
</div>
<button id="cmd">add a datepicker</button>




  $('#cmd').click(function(){
    $('#content').append('<br>a datepicker <input class="datepicker_recurring_start"/>');
});
$('body').on('focus',".datepicker_recurring_start", function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap do not include the date picker. You have to use jQuery UI for it.

See here:
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: tnx...i have made this using Jquery. But, why you said bootstrap don't have date picker? I have already use the date picker in bootstrap.

Comment: see this http://getbootstrap.com/ and datapiker link give to me!!!!! i can't find data piker here

Answer (score 3):

When you add the new datepicker it is important to call the $("#id_of_datepickercontainer").datepicker(); function to initialize the recently added datepicker.
Here is the example:

```js
function add_fields() {
  var newspan = document.createElement('span');
  newspan.innerHTML = '<div class="input-group" id="sandbox-container"><input type="text" placeholder="Date" class="form-control" name="date" id= "datefield" ><\/div><script>$("#sandbox-container input").datepicker({language: "hu"});<\/script>';
  document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(newspan);

  $("#sandbox-container input").datepicker();

}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.1/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <span>
    <div class="input-group" id="sandbox-container"><input type="text" placeholder="Date" class="form-control" name="date" id= "datefield" ></div>
    <script>$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker();</script>

  </span>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<input type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="New" class="btn btn-default" />
```

Comment: That's a nice example. How to add `Delete` button for deleting last elemen which has been added by the way?

Comment: How multiple same ids are handled by jquery in `add_fields` (`#sandbox-container`)? Can someone explain?